# How to manually set the "In-Reply-To" header in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I wanted to join a mailing list thread on a list to which I subscribed after the thread started. I wanted my reply to follow an existing message in the thread.

I researched how I could manually set the `In-Reply-To` header, finding [this](http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/thunderbird-threading.html) which basically suggests:

> it must be added to the list of custom headers by doing:
>
> ```
> Edit → Preferences → Advanced → General → Config Editor
> ```
>
> Search for `mail.compose.other.header` and add `In-Reply-To`
>
> Then `In-Reply-To` will show up as one of the options in the compose window in the same place where you can choose `To:`, `Cc:`, etc.

Well I did that, and the field did appear (after restarting Thunderbird). I entered the message id in the field and sent the messagge. But the header, although present, was blank:

```
To: "he...
In-Reply-To: 
From: ....
Subject: Re: ...
```

**Is it possible to manually set `In-Reply-To` in a Thunderbird message ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also bit by this same problem. I have then tried [the header-tools-lite extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/header-tools-lite/) that can be used to edit the header of email messages. I created a new message, saved it as draft, edited the header (References field) and finally sent the message. It seems to work fine.

Comment: Like `References: <message-id-whatever>`. Afaik angle brackets are important. Besides, it seems like [dev homepage](https://freeshell.de//~kaosmos/headertoolslite-en.html) has a more updated version.

Comment: unfortunately this does not works in TB 78

Answer (score 6):

As mirh hinted in the comments of Luca’s answer, it seems Thunderbird will throw out the `In-Reply-To` header value unless the message ID is surrounded in angle brackets.

So, instead of choosing `In-Reply-To:` as a header and entering the value `51506064.8010504@draigBrady.com`, instead use the value `<51506064.8010504@draigBrady.com>`.

I tested this on a Mailman list, and after additionally setting `CC:` to the mailing list email, my message was threaded properly in the list.

Comment: That means Thunderbird is correct, as RFC 5322 defines: <<msg-id = [CFWS] "<" id-left "@" id-right ">" [CFWS]>> (the correct syntax *requires* angle brackets)

Answer (score 3):

[comment 1189889/1098266](https://superuser.com/a/1189889/1098266) mentions using Header Tools Lite. This is an old XUL extension and no longer will work with Thunderbird 68+, developer says [on their website](http://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/headertoolslite-en.html):

> ## On the spotlight - END OF DEVELOPMENT AND SUPPORT
>
> As is well known, Mozilla has chosen to renounce XUL/XPCOM based technology for extensions and has decided to replace it with Webextensions.
>
> For non-experts, this means that extensions now use a completely different technology and that all "old style" extensions must be rewritten from scratch to work.
>
> Not having enough time and motivation for such a complicated job, as well as for personal reasons, **I decided to completely end the development and support of all my extensions.**

There is this alternative however, which is how I do it:

Borrowed from [MozillaZine: Custom headers](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Custom_headers). Archive link [1](https://archive.is/http://kb.mozillazine.org/Custom_headers), [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20190930123235/http://kb.mozillazine.org/Custom_headers). [Just in case it disappears](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=3055133).

1. Check the value of: `mail.identity.idX.useremail` to determine which index number refers to your email account. ie Edit → Preferences → Advanced → General → Config Editor
2. Set `user_pref("mail.identity.id1.headers", "References, InReplyTo");` to create the custom headers.
3. Change the custom headers, you could use a `user.js` for this.
4. Set the values for References, you can use as many `References` as you like, just make sure they are separated with a new-line character and a space ie: `\n`.
   `user_pref("mail.identity.id1.header.References", "References: <2ad46d80-c8ce-49a3-9896-16171788ac28@example.tld>\n <31ff00c2-b7cb-4063-beeb-a0bdd424c3a7@example1.tld>");`
5. Set the `In-Reply-To:` ie `user_pref("mail.identity.id1.header.InReplyTo", "In-Reply-To: <31ff00c2-b7cb-4063-beeb-a0bdd424c3a7@example1.tld>");`
6. Restart Thunderbird and send your email.
7. Comment out the above set options in your `user.js` with `/* */`. Go back into about:config ie (Edit → Preferences → Advanced → General → Config Editor) and rightclick on the keys `mail.identity.id1.headers`, `mail.identity.id1.header.References` and `mail.identity.id1.header.InReplyTo` and click *Reset*. Do not set these values to anything else in a `user.js`, because it will interfere with Thunderbird's normal behavior when you click Reply on an email.

Comment: +1 Very nice first answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [changeQuote](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/changequote/) add-on works well for me.